# How to make this code's design better?

Tags: go

[Github repo](https://github.com/puneet222/MyMoney)

I've attempted a backend assignment in Go from geektrust [Assignment Link](https://www.geektrust.in/coding-problem/backend/mymoney).
I'm not sure the code that I have written is idiomatic in the go way. I need some feedback on this code based on its extensibility, proper use of data structures.
How can this code be more improved?

Main build function of the project.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "geektrust/commander"
    "geektrust/portfolio"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    args := os.Args[1:]
    inputFile := "input.txt"
    if len(args) > 0 {
        inputFile = args[0]
    }
    // read input file
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(inputFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while reading file", err)
    }
    // generate commands from input file
    commands := commander.GenerateCommands(data)
    // generate portfolio from commands
    startYear := time.Now().Year()
    _ = portfolio.BuildPortfolio(commands, startYear)
}
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest avoid running the commands/build code if you received an error when reading the file. In the case of an error, I would prefer to not let the program continue. Below I used the `else` block, but you could also use `os.Exit(0)` to quit after an error (just beware that way doesn't run any defers).

Additionally, remove the blank identifier at `_ = portfolio...`.

```
func main() {
    args := os.Args[1:]
    inputFile := "input.txt"
    if len(args) > 0 {
        inputFile = args[0]
    }
    // read input file
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(inputFile)
    if err == nil {
        // generate commands from input file
        commands := commander.GenerateCommands(data)
        // generate portfolio from commands
        startYear := time.Now().Year()
        portfolio.BuildPortfolio(commands, startYear)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Error while reading file", err)
    }
}
```